# Horizontal Menu problem in IE6

Tags: html, css

My text menu items are not vertically aligning correctly in IE6 in my horizontal menu.

Example - http://blacktownworkersgroup.worldsecuresystems.com/bwc09/home

They seem to be ok in Firefox 3 and IE7.

I've made the background red for each item to make it more obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chage this class

```
#nav_468891 li { /* all list */
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
display: inline;
line-height: 30px;
```

}

you can delete "vertical-align: middle;"